# Glyph origin of 款

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin, character-components

Where does this character 款 come from? Its meanings (model/style or fee/payment) doesn't seem to have any link to the semantic part 欠, unless it specifically refers to owed money/payment?
And what does the left component mean? I haven't seen the left side (phonetic?) component in any other character before.

Comment: Have you checked [款](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AC%BE) ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as all the other answers are getting downvoted - I'll just leave this short reference here:

**Outlier**

> **FORM**
> 款 kuǎn was originally composed of 柰 nài (now written ) and 欠 “person with their mouth open,” which hints at the original meaning “to desire something that one does not have.” 柰 gave the sound (but for the reading kuài).
>
> **COMPONENTS**
>
> In 款 kuǎn,  is an empty component. It was originally 柰 nài, which was the sound component (but for the reading kuài).
> 欠
> In 款, 欠 “person with their mouth open” is a meaning component, hinting at the original meaning “to desire something that one does not have.”
>
> **MEANINGS**
> **kuǎn**
> 1 (orig.) to desire something that one does not have
> 2 ○ sum of money, fund
> 3 → wealth; wealthy person
> 4 → item
> 5 ⇒ clause in a document

- The meaning of money/funds is again another **phonetic loan**, indicated by the ○ symbol on definition number two.

The reference Outlier gives here is from:

> p. 768
> 李學勤，2012《字源》，天津：天津古籍出版社，2013年7月2次印刷。

and here is the excerpt from Ziyuan:

> [image]

and its extracted text:

> 形声字。《说文》：“款，意有所欲也。从欠，窾省声。歀，款或从柰。”姚文田、严可均校议：“当作祟声，小徐．《韵会》十四旱引作嶔省声。”徐濒段注笺：“窾之声转如窜，故《系传》作窾省声。然窾本从款声，款不得义从窾省声。此鼎臣所以删声字也。窃谓款当从祟声，读苦外切，故字又作歀，从柰即其明证。款或作款，正与隸或作隷同也。救乃诚款本字，其义为空虚，故从宀相承省作款耳。款从祟声，明白无可疑者，今径正之。”清邵瑛群经正字：“凡篆文偏旁出字，隶法当作土。”《说文》所释“意有所欲也”，当为款字本义，因为从欠为意符。战国秦汉文献多用为诚实之义，当为借义，用为空义，本字也作嶔。款字当以柰为声符，祟当是柰之讹变。桌是柰之隶变减省。款字未见于西周金文，也未见于西周文献，其字当产生于春秋战国时代。（周宝宏）

- If you're curious about the, original, "⿰柰" portion of the character it is interesting that we can see a similar progression in 隸. This character later became: 隷. Where again ⿰柰 evolved into: ⿰.

This one makes me laugh because of the internet slang pun that can often be found associated with [柰](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E6%9F%B0%E5%AD%90%0D%0A). Especially, here, situated next to an open mouth. But, perhaps that reinforces the *desire* for something you don't have.

Answer (score 3):

| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) 璽印 | [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: 李歀] | [image: 歀] | [image: 款] | [image: 款] |
| 「李歀」 十鐘山房印舉3.34 | [欠部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=31) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)・或體 | 80甲 武威醫簡 |  |

「款」 was originally written as 「歀」, and the reference in 李學勤《字源》 claims that 「款」 was constructed for a sound like **/*kʰʷraːds/** ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995))), making 「柰」 (**/*naːds/**) the sound component. 「款」 was later used for **/*kʰloːnʔ/** (Mandarin Pinyin: **kuǎn**), and 「柰」 was later corrupted into 「⿱士示」.

「款」 (*empty/hollow* [now written 「窾」], *wanting*) uses 「欠」 (*to lack*) as a semantic component. The common meanings in use today are most likely phonetic loans.

---

**References:**

- 李學勤《字源》
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)

Answer (score -1):

欠is a Independent character. 欠 can be combined with other component  to form a character. The left component of 款 is not a character, it just forms part of the  character（款）, and it has no meaning.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question on how the components of 款 are formed. 欠 is supposed to be radical or semantic meaning, yet the meaning of 款 has no semantic link to "breathing" as most of the characters with 欠 have some sort of link to it (欲, 欺, 吹). As for the left part, I am curious how it came about because no other characters have that component, so I am unsure if it's a phonetic component, or does it add some meaning to the character 款.

Answer (score -1):

It was a independent character from the very beginning and had nothing to do with “欠”. The earliest version of "款" we know today came from the warring states period (the left one)

[image]

"欠" at that time was something like "专". It became the "欠" you know today at Han dynasty (a few hundred years later). It was just a coincidence they developed into the same shape.

BTW, 款 at the beginning didn't mean "fee/payment". It meant “sincere”, and today it still has this meaning when you use words like “款款”

Comment: `"欠" at that time was something like "专". It became the "欠" you know today at Han dynasty (a few hundred years later)` You're confusing functional character components with character shapes.